# Sort postcodes alphabetically and numerically?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database table of postcodes that are simply stored with the first part of the postcode. When I query the table and order by postcode I get this result:
    HG1
     - HG2
     - HG3
     - HG4

```
 - HU1
 - HU10
 - HU13
 - HU2
 - HU3
 - HU4
 - HU5
 - HU6
 - HU7
 - HU8
 - HU9

 - HX1
 - HX2
 - HX3
 - HX4
 - HX5
 - HX6

 - LN1
 - LN2
 - LN4
 - LN5
 - LN6
```

What I want is the postcodes listed in numerical order as well as alphabetical. I have tried using order by length but this messes with the alphabetical order as it puts any with 2 characters before any with 3 etc so I end up with:
     - S6
     - S8

```
 - S9

 - B66

 - BB5
 - BB6

 - BD2
 - BD3
 - BD4
 - BD5
 - BD6
 - BD7
 - BD8
 - BD9
```

Is there any way to fix this without adding extra columns in the database?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sougata's answer will do it, but in PHP - so you'd need to query the entire result set and then sort it.

If you want to do this sort natively in the query, you can use regexp to work out whether the postcode has 1 or 2 letters, then split it into two parts (letters/numbers) and do a subsort with the numbers `CAST` to unsigned integers:

```
SELECT postcode FROM test
ORDER BY
    IF(postcode REGEXP '[A-Z]{2}', LEFT(postcode, 2), LEFT(postcode, 1)) ASC,
    IF(postcode REGEXP '[A-Z]{2}', CONVERT(MID(postcode, 3, LENGTH(postcode) - 2), UNSIGNED), CONVERT(MID(postcode, 2, LENGTH(postcode) - 1), UNSIGNED)) ASC
```

[image]

Comment: I've just tried this ORDER BY
    IF(post_code REGEXP '[A-Z]{2}', LEFT(post_code, 2), LEFT(post_code, 1)) ASC,
    IF(post_code REGEXP '[A-Z]{2}', MID(post_code, 3, LENGTH(post_code) - 2), MID(post_code, 2, LENGTH(post_code) - 1)) ASC     and I get the same result :(

Comment: Odd. I've just added a screenshot of my results when running this query.

Comment: Your screenshot confirms that this isn't the desired order - note the position of HU10 between HU1 and HU2, rather than after HU9.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I'll try casting that to an integer. BRB!

Comment: I've updated the answer and the screenshot, hopefully it's correct this time!

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you so much for this! All working perfectly now :)

Answer (score 1):

[natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) should work.

> This function implements a sort algorithm that orders alphanumeric strings in the way a human being would while maintaining key/value associations.

```
$arr = [
'S9',
'B66',
'BB5',
'BB6',
'BD2',
'BD3',
'BD4',
'BD5',
'BD6',
'BD7',
'BD8',
'BD9'
];
natsort ($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => B66
    [2] => BB5
    [3] => BB6
    [4] => BD2
    [5] => BD3
    [6] => BD4
    [7] => BD5
    [8] => BD6
    [9] => BD7
    [10] => BD8
    [11] => BD9
    [0] => S9
)
```